# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 with ChromeDriver and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to extract data from following website :https://www.bigschedules.com/
which works normally when I do it manually.

I have developed a script using selenium and Chromedriver in Python, It used to work fine before but now, it shows error "**Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200**.

The script opens chrome and tries to get data from the website but gets stuck as seen in the picture below:
[Click here to see image][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JxEi.png`enter code here`

I'm using chromedriver version 2.42, Selenium version 3.14

```
def setupChrome(self):

    # Contains all chrome settings
    self.logger.info("Setting-up Chrome")
    self.settings = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    #self.settings.add_argument("--incognito")
    self.settings.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
    self.settings.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    self.settings.add_argument('–-disable-web-security')
    self.settings.add_argument('–-allow-running-insecure-content')

def loadBrowser(self):
    self.setupChrome()

    try:
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.settings,
                                        executable_path="D:\\chromedriver.exe")
        self.browser.maximize_window()
```

& I am getting following errors in console stack:

```
webtrends.js:1 **A parser-blocking**, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://sdc.oocl.com/dcsg6upoljf1zldtivsnov48s_8o7d/wtid.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
WebTrends.dcsGetId @ webtrends.js:1
(anonymous) @ VM29:431

6[Intervention] **Slow network is detected**. See <URL> for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: <URL>
application-c962374717.min.js:4 

pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization: **No sanitization** strategy has been configured. This can have serious security implications. See http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security for details.
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:4
warn @ application-c962374717.min.js:12
c @ angular-translate.min.js:6
sanitize @ angular-translate.min.js:6
a.interpolate @ angular-translate.min.js:6
q.instant @ angular-translate.min.js:6
n @ angular-translate.min.js:6
fn @ VM201:4
e @ angular.js:16658
P.exp @ angular.js:13144
pre @ angular.js:10436
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1385
wa @ angular.js:10545
q @ angular.js:9911
f @ angular.js:9174
q @ angular.js:9928
f @ angular.js:9174
q @ angular.js:9928
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10273
(anonymous) @ angular.js:17051
$digest @ angular.js:18233
$apply @ angular.js:18531
l @ angular.js:12547
s @ angular.js:12785
y.onload @ angular.js:12702
application-c962374717.min.js:4 

Deprecation warning: **moment().add(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().add(number, period). See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/add-inverted-param/ for more info.**
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:4
k @ moment-with-locales.min.js:1
T @ moment-with-locales.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ moment-with-locales.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:44
invoke @ angular.js:5040
P.instance @ angular.js:11000
q @ angular.js:9865
f @ angular.js:9174
f @ angular.js:9177
f @ angular.js:9177
f @ angular.js:9177
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9039
(anonymous) @ angular.js:9430
d @ angular.js:9217
m @ angular.js:9984
(anonymous) @ angular.js:32398
(anonymous) @ angular.js:1385
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10539
wa @ angular.js:10545
q @ angular.js:9934
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10273
(anonymous) @ angular.js:17051
$digest @ angular.js:18233
$apply @ angular.js:18531
l @ angular.js:12547
s @ angular.js:12785
y.onload @ angular.js:12702
universalModuleDefinition:3 

WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.bigschedules.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=yywiluhT_bdXDglEAAkc' failed: **Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200**


n.doOpen @ universalModuleDefinition:3
n.open @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.probe @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.onOpen @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.onHandshake @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.onPacket @ universalModuleDefinition:2
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.emit @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.onPacket @ universalModuleDefinition:2
r @ universalModuleDefinition:2
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:2
e.decodePayloadAsBinary @ universalModuleDefinition:2
e.decodePayload @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.onData @ universalModuleDefinition:2
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:2
n.emit @ universalModuleDefinition:2
i.onData @ universalModuleDefinition:2
i.onLoad @ universalModuleDefinition:2
hasXDR.r.onreadystatechange @ universalModuleDefinition:2
application-c962374717.min.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot assign to read only property 'tagName' of object '#<HTMLDivElement>'**
    at Object.handler.tagNameHandler (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at Object.handler.constructInfo (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.tagNameHandler @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.constructInfo @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
4application-c962374717.min.js:23

Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot assign to read only property** 'tagName' of object '#<HTMLInputElement>'
    at Object.handler.tagNameHandler (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at Object.handler.constructInfo (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.tagNameHandler @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.constructInfo @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
application-c962374717.min.js:23

Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot assign to read only property** 'tagName' of object '[object HTMLAnchorElement]'
    at Object.handler.tagNameHandler (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at Object.handler.constructInfo (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.tagNameHandler @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.constructInfo @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
query:1 **Failed to load resource**: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
application-c962374717.min.js:23 

Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot assign to read only property** 'tagName' of object '[object HTMLAnchorElement]'
    at Object.handler.tagNameHandler (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at Object.handler.constructInfo (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at tracking (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at firstThingAfterSearch (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at monitor (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.tagNameHandler @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.constructInfo @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
tracking @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
firstThingAfterSearch @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
monitor @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
wrappedFn @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
angular.js:12759 GET https://www.bigschedules.com/api/routeSearch/query?_=1537193893310&carrier=COSU&carrier=APLU&carrier=MSCU&departureFrom=2018-09-17T00:00:00.000Z&departureTo=2018-09-30T23:59:59.999Z&fndID=P1015&isOriginal=true&porID=P94&requestRefNo=432d9035-b7bb-40d9-b03f-208ffcbdafa3&socketID=yywiluhT_bdXDglEAAkc **401 (Unauthorized)**
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12759
q @ angular.js:12492
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12244
(anonymous) @ angular.js:17051
$digest @ angular.js:18233
(anonymous) @ angular.js:18462
e @ angular.js:6362
(anonymous) @ angular.js:6642
setTimeout (async)
h.defer @ angular.js:6640
$evalAsync @ angular.js:18460
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16923
k @ angular.js:17095
l @ angular.js:17122
c @ angular.js:17131
r @ bluebird.min.js:31
i._settlePromiseFromHandler @ bluebird.min.js:30
i._settlePromise @ bluebird.min.js:30
i._settlePromise0 @ bluebird.min.js:30
i._settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:30
r._drainQueue @ bluebird.min.js:29
r._drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:29
drainQueues @ bluebird.min.js:29
Promise.then (async)
r @ bluebird.min.js:30
r._queueTick @ bluebird.min.js:29
s @ bluebird.min.js:29
p.hasDevTools.r.settlePromises @ bluebird.min.js:29
i._fulfill @ bluebird.min.js:30
i._resolveCallback @ bluebird.min.js:30
(anonymous) @ bluebird.min.js:30
Do @ recaptcha__en.js:251
(anonymous) @ recaptcha__en.js:249
T4 @ recaptcha__en.js:71
ta @ recaptcha__en.js:71
Y @ recaptcha__en.js:68
application-c962374717.min.js:23 

Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot assign to read only property** 'tagName' of object '[object HTMLAnchorElement]'
    at Object.handler.tagNameHandler (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at Object.handler.constructInfo (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at tracking (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at firstThingAfterSearch (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at monitor (application-c962374717.min.js:23)
    at application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.tagNameHandler @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
handler.constructInfo @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
tracking @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
firstThingAfterSearch @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
monitor @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
wrappedFn @ application-c962374717.min.js:23
angular.js:12759 

GET https://www.bigschedules.com/api/routeSearch/query?_=1537193947261&carrier=COSU&carrier=APLU&carrier=MSCU&departureFrom=2018-09-17T00:00:00.000Z&departureTo=2018-09-30T23:59:59.999Z&fndID=P156&isOriginal=true&porID=P94&requestRefNo=ba8fbb09-d98a-4b44-96e0-040511775c80&socketID=yywiluhT_bdXDglEAAkc **401 (Unauthorized)**
```

Comment: Seems to be CORS issue. Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: @Newcontributor I am a beginner. I don't know how to get the error stack trace. Kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: Instead/In addition to the snapshot of the _Development Tool Console_ update the question with the complete error you are seeing on the console in text format.

Comment: @Newcontributor Added console text. There are few others that are tags related which arose due to unable to find element on the page.

Comment: You need to update the question with the error trace logs **as it is** which helps us to debug the actual issue. Else debugging the error is impossible.

Comment: @Newcontributor Updated it with complete console text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code trials it wasn't evident whether you have invoked the *url* `https://www.bigschedules.com/tou` or not. But as per your *error stack trace* your main issue is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.bigschedules.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=yywiluhT_bdXDglEAAkc' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

There can be numerous reasons behind the error as follows:

- A potential reason may be, the network request for this script may be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity.
- As per [Intervention: Blocking the load of cross-origin, parser-blocking scripts inserted via document.write for users on 2G](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104):

  - > For users on slow connections such as 2G, the performance penalty from third-party scripts loaded via document.write is often so severe as to delay display of main page content for tens of seconds. This feature will block the load of cross-origin, parser-blocking scripts inserted via document.write in case of an HTTP cache miss for users on a 2G connection. The feature will only be applicable to such scripts in the main frame.
- Another reason can be, a slow network was detected and **Fallback font** was used while loading which is configured with **No sanitization** strategy and have a serious security implications. Hence you face:

  ```
  response code: 200
  ```

### Solution

- Keep your *Test Environment* updated with all the latest binaries in terms of **Selenium Client**, **WebDriver** and **Web Browser** variant.
- Configure your *Test Environment* with a faster network e.g **3G** or **4G**

Comment: As script opens url in incognito, the https://www.bigschedules.com/tou opens up and script accept cookies and goes to main page. It Enter parameters in fields and goes to extract data but gets stuck at www.bigschedules.com/routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **urllib2** , **BeautifulSoup** for this issue on Pyhton. 
Below code example show you how to get attributes of page elements from page source.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

page = urllib2.urlopen('yourUrl')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
elementsYouWantToExtract = soup.findAll('element tag for instance: "img" ')
for attributeYouWantToExtract in elementsYouWantToExtract:
    print elementsYouWantToSearch['attributeYouWantToExtract']
```

Hope it will help...